# How to get EditText ID

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have added some EditTexts using a loop,

textFieldsLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.LinearLayout2);

```
    for(int i=1; i <= 8; i++){

        final EditText ed = new EditText(this);

        ed.setText("" + i);

        ed.setInputType(2);

        ed.setLayoutParams(lparams);

        textFieldsLayout.addView(ed);
    }   
}
```

After this I want to get the text that the user adds into the EditText fields, but I am stuck on how to do this. How would I get an Id for each of these EditText Fields?

Thanks, Oli

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just add them to a collection when you're creating them that you can easily refer to by index or key or loop through or otherwise.

```
EditText[] etCollection = new EditText[8];

..........

    textFieldsLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.LinearLayout2);
    for(int i=1; i <= 8; i++){
        final EditText ed = new EditText(this);
        ed.setText("" + i);
        ed.setInputType(2);
        ed.setLayoutParams(lparams);
        textFieldsLayout.addView(ed);
        etCollection[i] = ed; <------ adding them to the collection
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to do `ed.setId( id );` on each one your create, and `id` should be unique for each one you want to find.  When you go to find one do

```
EditText ed = (EditText)findViewById( id );
```

You'll have to keep track of your ids somewhere.

Alternatively you can just keep a list of the EditTexts that you create and run through the list to get the text of each one.

Comment: I was about to reply the same, but (my curiosity) how one can be sure that id won't collide with some automatic id give from @+id ?

Comment: I don't think you can.  Keeping a list of them is probably the better way to do it.

Comment: XML-generated IDs start at 0x7f000000, and framework IDs are all 
above 0x800...0.

Comment: There you go, just keep your IDs below 0x7f000000 and you should be fine.  I was referring to a [List](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/List.html) in code to hold the created EditTexts.  Might still be easier to do it with a list depending on what exactly is happening.